# Getting flicker from transparent PNG used as mouseover image

Tags: javascript, png, mouseover

I did a little bit of poking around for this, but couldn't find the exact thing I am trying to do here. Basically I have an image map, where I wanted to have hidden layers appear over the top of the image on mouseover. There are 5 different hotspots, and 5 different hidden layers that correspond, and show up only when you mouseover the corresponding hotspot.

The problem is this: each of the hidden layers on top contains a PNG with transparent bits, and the PNG is revealed pretty much in the same spot where the user's mouse is. When it is called up by a mouseover, the PNG flickers rapidly...I presume because the page is having trouble determining whether the mouse is over or off the image, due to its transparency...?

Anyone have a clever solution to this?

I've got this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
function HideContent(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function ShowContent(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}
function ReverseContentDisplay(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
//-->
</script>
```

And this in the body of the page:

```
<div id="homeowners" 
   style="display:none; 
      position:absolute; 
      left:0px; 
      top:39px; 
      padding: 5px;
      z-index:10;">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/homeowners-over.png" width="257" height="107" alt="Homeowners" /></div>
<div id="dealers" 
   style="display:none; 
      position:absolute; 
      left:319px; 
      top:39px; 
      padding: 5px;
      z-index:10;">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/dealers-over.png" width="257" height="107" alt="Dealers" /></div>
<div id="commercial" 
   style="display:none; 
      position:absolute; 
      left:0px; 
      top:509px; 
      padding: 5px;
      z-index:10;">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/commercial-over.png" width="257" height="107" alt="Commercial" /></div>
<div id="importers" 
   style="display:none; 
      position:absolute; 
      left:319px; 
      top:509px; 
      padding: 5px;
      z-index:10;">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/importers-over.png" width="257" height="107" alt="Importers" /></div>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/aww_home.jpg" width="586" height="638" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="poly" coords="3,4,293,4,293,25,4,313" href="#"
   onmouseover="ShowContent('homeowners'); return true;"
   href="javascript:ShowContent('homeowners')" 
   onmouseout="HideContent('homeowners'); return true;"
   href="javascript:HideContent('homeowners')">
      <area shape="poly" coords="296,5,583,4,584,312,296,27" href="#"
   onmouseover="ShowContent('dealers'); return true;"
   href="javascript:ShowContent('dealers')" 
   onmouseout="HideContent('dealers'); return true;"
   href="javascript:HideContent('dealers')">
      <area shape="poly" coords="294,32,8,317,295,603,575,318" href="#" />
      <area shape="poly" coords="5,322,4,633,294,634,294,608" href="#"
   onmouseover="ShowContent('commercial'); return true;"
   href="javascript:ShowContent('commercial')" 
   onmouseout="HideContent('commercial'); return true;"
   href="javascript:HideContent('commercial')">
      <area shape="poly" coords="299,607,299,634,582,634,580,325" href="#"
   onmouseover="ShowContent('importers'); return true;"
   href="javascript:ShowContent('importers')" 
   onmouseout="HideContent('importers'); return true;"
   href="javascript:HideContent('importers')">
    </map>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned on which elements you have added mouseover and mouseout event handlers, I am going to assume that you are calling `showContent` to show png when mouse is moved over the div and you are calling `hideContent` to hide the png when mouse is over the png.

If this is what is happening then the reason for the flicker is:

When mouse is moved over div, the png is shown over the div. Therefore the mouse is now over png due to which mouseover event is fired on png which hides it. Now the mouse is over the div therefore, the mouseover event is fired on div due to which png is shown. This will keep on going.

Solutions:
1. Place the png (on showing) a little further from the mouse so that the png is not directly below the mouse cursor.
2. Or, remove the mouseover event handler from the png and add the mouseout handler to div to hide the png.

Comment: That's not exactly it in terms of the way I have the events set, but I think you are getting at the basic problem-- I've attached the mouseout event to the wrong thing. The mouseover and mouseout events are both applied to hotspot areas on the image UNDERNEATH the hidden PNGs. You've given me a really good clue here...I think I need to somehow set the mouseout event differently. I'm gong to go try something and will report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my problem when I added .show to the element that pops up as well. The browser was getting confused when my mouse would transition from one element to the other.

```
$(function () {
    $('.parent_div').hover(function () {
        $('.show_popup').show();
    }, function () {
        $('.show_popup').hide();
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.show_popup').hover(function () {
        $('.show_popup').show();
    });
});
```